# TortoiseGit "SSL tlsv1 alert protocol version" issue

Tags: git, ssl, tortoisegit

Since today, my TortoiseGit start throwing

```
"error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"
```

error during pull/push default operations.

Os : windows 7

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I have the same issue in TortoiseGit, though my command line git (as discussed in the other thread) is working fine.  This question requires a TortoiseGit-specific answer ... though the solution presented by @Nigrimmist is indeed proposed in the other thread (though this did not work for my TortoiseGit instance).

Answer (score 2):

The Fastest solution i found is to download Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0 - check latest) and push from it works well, but it's not a general solution, still trying to solve it.

Also, check please https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/ - it's a reason of that issue with few provided solutions